# AngularUI for AngularJS counting the "uniqe" filter results

Tags: angularjs, angular-ui

I'm using AngularUI 'unique' filter to show a list of only unique items. My question is how I can also get the count of the number of items in each unique result?

e.g. set is:

```
colors = [
{name:'black', shade:'dark'},
{name:'white', shade:'light'},
{name:'red', shade:'dark'},
{name:'red', shade:'dark'},
{name:'yellow', shade:'light'}
]
```

And in the view:

```
<li ng-repeat="color in colors | unique:'name'">{{color.name}}</li>
```

Gives:

```
<li>black</li>
<li>white</li>
<li>red</li>
<li>yellow</li>
```

I wish to also show in the view that black count is 1, red is 2, etc..

Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I dont think the filter can change the base structure this way. 
You'l have to preproccess the collection in your controller

With `lodash` for example

```
collection = [{name:'a'},{name:'b'},{name:'a'},{name:'c'}];
_.mapValues(_.groupBy(collection, 'name'), function(r) { return r.length; });
Object {a: 2, b: 1, c: 1}
```

Then iterate the collection in your ng-repeat

Comment: Thanks, I used Undersocre.js and basically did what you have suggested

Answer (score 0):

The following should provide you with a property containing the filtered list. from there you can call .length to get the length of the list

```
<li ng-repeat="color in filteredList = (colors | unique:'name')">{{color.name}}</li>
<div>{{filteredList.length}}</div>
```